# Laravel Eloquent for Social Network

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, mode

[image: User->post->likes]

I'm building a social network. I have *Users* and *Posts*. for *like* concept I created a table (Likes):
 `_______________________
|id | post_id | user_id |
|   |         |         |`

I want to show people who like a post below each post.
so I need to save a row for each *Like*
.
My problem is Eloquent and how to save a *Like* row

```
    $post = Post::find($request->postId);
    $like = new Likes();
    $user = $request->user();
    $post->likes()->save($like, $user);
    return 'done';
```

this code set user_id (Likes tabel) 0

*is there a better way for Like Concept?*

Comment: The concept is fine, that's how you'd handle such a relationship.

Comment: If you want likes for posts only, this is fine, but if in the future you need likes for comments, or photos, or etc. you should consider using a polymorphic relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller use this method  :
    public function postLikePost(Request $request)
    {
        $post_id = $request['postId'];
        $is_like = $request['isLike'] === 'true' ? true:false;
        $update = false;
        $post = Post::find($post_id);
        if(!$post){
            return null;
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $like = $user->likes()->where('post_id',$post_id)->first();
        if($like){
            $liked = $like->likes;
            $update = true;
            if($liked == $is_like)
            {
                $like->delete();
                return null;
            }
        } else
        {
            $like = new Like();
            //die($like);
        }

```
    $like->likes = $is_like;
    $like->user_id = $user->id;
    $like->post_id = $post->id;
    if($update){
        $like->update();
    }
    else{
        $like->save();
    }
    return null;
    }
```